# Not possible to get value from SQL temporary table in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

This code works for me.

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from tbl_rating limit 1 ;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

   echo $row["NameA"];

}
```

However, this code does not work. Can anyone point out my mistakes? Thanks.

```
$result = mysql_query("create temporary table ub_rank as 
select similar.NameA,count(*) rank
from tbl_rating target 
join tbl_rating similar on target.NameB= similar.NameB and target.NameA != similar.NameA and target.Rate= similar.Rate 
where target.NameA = 'tutorA'
group by similar.NameA;

select * from ub_rank limit 1 ;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row["NameA"];

  }
```

Error msg:

**Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource**

But, I wondering why I can get the value in the first code with the same structure?!

Comment: you can't put 2 queries in one mysql_query function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` does not support multiple queries in a pass. You'll need to break the query into two separate calls:

```
mysql_query("create temporary table ub_rank as 
  select similar.NameA,count(*) rank
  from tbl_rating target 
  join tbl_rating similar on target.NameB= similar.NameB and target.NameA !=  similar.NameA and target.Rate= similar.Rate 
  where target.NameA = 'tutorA'
  group by similar.NameA
");
$result = mysql_query("select * from ub_rank limit 1 ;");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row["NameA"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()`, which you should not be using anyway since it is deprecated, will not allow you to execute multiple queries in a single call like that. Technically, there is a hackish way to fudge it to execute multiple queries but it will only provide the result set from the first.

You need to execute these queries separately.  Or if you convert to using `mysqli` you can use `mysqli_multi_query`, however thatt is really only useful for cases where you don't need the result set.